# There is no 'denying' or 'deny'?

Tags: negation, infinitive-vs-gerund

CONTEXT

1: There is no denying that Americans are great.(correct)
2: There is no deny that Americans are great.(incorrect)

Why can't I use deny , I know that it is incorrect but what is the justification for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use an infinitive (first/base form of a verb) after the phrase "there's no". For examples, you don't say there's no ask, there's no eat, there's no sit here, etc.  You need a noun, noun phrase, or a gerund participle that acts as a noun such as telling, eating  asking, sitting, denying.

There's no denying......

The "denying" is a gerund in the sentence, so it's grammatical in the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The *-ing* form of the verb is necessary when making negative

> no denying
>   no telling
>   no walking
>   no smoking

You second sentence would be correct as

> There is *no one who can* deny that Americans are great.